# After inserting value in a form using jsp, return a message with the values inserted on top of the form page

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have a form that after pressing the Add button, goes to a DataInsert.jsp
After running the insertion, just bejore the end ()
I want to put a message "Inserted" and redirect to the home page.

I have something like this (form in index.jsp):

```
<form onsubmit="return checkempty(form1)" action="Data_insert.jsp" method="post" name="form1">

  <table class="table" width="25%">
    <tr>
      <td><label for="name">Name:  </label></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="city">City: </label></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="city" id="city"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Add"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <p><br>
  </p>
</form>
```

The insertion is done in: Data_insert.jsp

```
<body>
<%
    String name=request.getParameter("name");
    String city=request.getParameter("city");

    // Connect to the database using Tomcat Resources
    Context ctx = null;
    Context initCtx = null;
    Connection con = null;
    DataSource ds = null;

    ctx = new InitialContext();
    initCtx = (Context) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env");
    ds = (DataSource) initCtx.lookup("jdbc/table_pool");
    con = ds.getConnection();

    PreparedStatement stmt;
    String instruccionSql="INSERT INTO table (name,city) VALUES ('" + name + "','" + city + "')";
    stmt = con.prepareStatement(instruccionSql);
    stmt.executeUpdate();
    stmt.close();
    con.close();

    out.println("Insertado"+"<br>");
%>
</body>
```

The problem is that the messages "Inserted" clears the screen.
If we put a Javascript alert, 
window.alert("Inserted!");
It does not appear as an alert box,

We have also tried:

```
<script>
    window.location.href = '/index.jsp';
</script>
```

It redirects to the page, but we do not see the Inserted message as a popup.

How can I make to get the "Inserted" message as a pop-up, on top of the home page.
Thanks

Comment: so above code is in `DataInsert.jsp` or your `index.jsp`?

Comment: Thanks Swati, yes I added that part at the end of "DataInsert.jsp". 
I also played adding the notification at the end of "index.jsp". 
But I think it should be better to add it at "DataInsert.jsp", and show somthing like "Inserted, value1= xxx, value2= yyy". 

If there is code that works on "index.jsp" it would be also fine. 
I also tried moving to index.jsp: window.alert("Inserted!"); (it works slightly better). 

I also tried in index.jsp: var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
window.alert("Inserted!" + name)

Comment: So, now you want to show alert on same page or redirect page ?

Comment: Hi Swati ! index.jsp is the form page, that calls DataInsert.jsp (code that performs the real insert) on the background. I would like to see the "Inserted!" alert on top of index.jsp. Currently, if I do not redirect from DataInsert.jsp to index.jsp, after inserting I see a blank page. I am not sure if it is all related to: <form onsubmit="return checkempty(form1)" action="Data_insert.jsp" method="post" name="form1">

Comment: can you edit your question and include related code ? now it is unclear without seeing more code i cannot tell you anything .Also you can `setAttribute` with some data in `DataInsert.jsp` and then check at `index.jsp` if the value is set or not depending on that you can show `alert`.

Comment: Hi Swati, I have updates with the base code !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setAttribute` to set some message in it and depending on that alert will be display on your `index.jsp` page.Like below :

```
<%
String name=request.getParameter("name"); 
String city=request.getParameter("city");
int row=0; 
  // Connect to the database using Tomcat Resources
    Context ctx = null;
    Context initCtx = null;
    Connection con = null;
    DataSource ds = null;

    ctx = new InitialContext();
    initCtx = (Context) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env");
    ds = (DataSource) initCtx.lookup("jdbc/table_pool");
    con = ds.getConnection();

    PreparedStatement stmt;
     String instruccionSql="INSERT INTO table (name,city) VALUES (?,?)";
    stmt = con.prepareStatement(instruccionSql);
    stmt.setString(1,name); 
    stmt.setString(2,city); 

    row=stmt.executeUpdate();
    stmt.close();
    con.close();
  //if inserted
    if (row > 0) { 
  //setting message
      session.setAttribute("add", "Added Succesfully"); 
  //redirecting
      request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request,response);
    } 

%>
```

Then in `index.jsp` do like below :

```
  <% if(session.getAttribute("add") != null){ %>
    <script>
   alert("${add}");
   </script>
  <% } %>
```

Or use `EL` add below line above your `<form>` tag :

```
 <p style="color: red;text-align:center">${add}</p>
```

Comment: Hi Swati, both options work fantastic. Thank you so much !!